# Electron start script error

Tags: windows, electron, exe, electron-builder, electron-packager

i am running a webpack project and running this script 

My **package.json** looks like this

```
{
    "name": "collab-ui",
    "version": "0.0.10",
    "author": {
        "name": "some-name",
        "email": "some-emailId"
    },
    "main": "electron.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "rimraf debug && npm outdated && webpack --watch",
        "http": "rimraf debug && npm outdated && webpack --watch",
        "release": "rimraf dist && webpack --bail --progress --profile",
        "elecstart": "rimraf debug && webpack &&  electron .",
        "elecrel": "electron-packager . XorChat --all",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
        "api-ai-javascript": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
        "autoprefixer": "~6.7.7",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.2",
        "browser-sync": "~2.18.8",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "~1.1.4",
        "css-loader": "~0.27.3",
        "custom-event-polyfill": "~0.3.0",
        "electron": "^1.7.9",
        "electron-packager": "^9.1.0",
        "es6-promise": "~4.1.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.1.0",
        "file-loader": "~0.10.1",
        "html-loader": "~0.4.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "~2.28.0",
        "html5-notification": "~3.0.0",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.17.4",
        "import-glob-loader": "~1.1.0",
        "knockout": "~3.4.2",
        "live-server": "~1.2.0",
        "node-sass": "~4.5.0",
        "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "~0.0.5",
        "postcss-loader": "~1.3.3",
        "qrcode-generator": "~1.3.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "~2.1.0",
        "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
        "sass-loader": "~6.0.3",
        "socket.io-client": "~2.0.3",
        "store": "~2.0.12",
        "style-loader": "~0.14.1",
        "ts-loader": "~2.0.2",
        "typescript": "~2.2.1",
        "url-loader": "~0.5.8",
        "webpack": "~2.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "~1.10.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "~2.17.1",
        "webpack-stream": "~3.2.0",
        "webrtc-adapter": "^6.0.2",
        "uuid": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

My  **electron.js** looks like this

```
const electron = require('electron');
 const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
 app.commandLine.appendSwitch("ignore-certificate-errors");
 app.on('ready', () => {

     let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
     win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/debug/index.html`);
     win.webContents.openDevTools();
 })
```

But after running **npm run elecstart**, i am getting this error
[image]

Any clue,why i am getting this error. i am running on windows 10 64bit, 8 gb ram(FYI), but after running the script the window error box comes as shown in the image and after i close it , the script halts.I am suspecting some JS error to be in there, as it is not able to find some symbol or some configuration is missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried, uninstall and install *npm* package? Is Electron getting started tutorial working fine on your machine?

Comment: i didnt give it a try. But i will and keep u updated